# Build not set indefinitely by RM

Tags: ms-release-management, tfs-2015

The combination of XAML build definition that is triggering a release was setting the build to be retained **indefinitely**.

The new non-XAML build doesn't get set to be retained indefinitely by the TFS RM releases.

Am I missing something or I have to set through code?

On-prem TFS.

Answer (score 3):

You're not missing anything. The behavior is different for the new build system, and I'm glad that it is. It tended to be a problem more often than it was a benefit.

Comment: This can cause problems to the RM releases which are triggered before the expiration of build retention policies: if the build has 20days retention policy and the release to a stage is triggered after 21days then RM server will not find the build drop folder.